# Tic Tac Toe C program not executing correctly

Tags: c

I wrote two functions for the two players. And one function to check winning conditions. The program executes correctly except it doesn't detect when someone wins. So there must be some problem with the check function.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int P1(int, char []), P2(int, char []), check( int, char []);
int main()
{
    char a[10]= "---------" ;
    int flag= 3, p, q;
    while( flag== 3)
    {   
        P1( p, a);  
        check( flag, a); 
        if( flag== 1)
        {   printf("P1 WINS");}
        else
        {
            P2( q, a);
            check( flag, a);
            if( flag== 2)
            {printf("P2 WINS");}
        }
    }
return 0;}

int P1(int p, char a[10])
{
    printf("P1: Which position?\n");
    scanf("%d", &p);
    a[p-1]= 'X';
    printf("%c %c %c\n%c %c %c\n%c %c %c\n", a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4], a[5], a[6], a[7], a[8]);return 0;
}

int P2(int q, char a[10])
{   
    printf("P2: Which position?\n");
    scanf("%d", &q);
    a[q-1]= '0';
    printf("%c %c %c\n%c %c %c\n%c %c %c\n", a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4], a[5], a[6], a[7], a[8]);return 0;
}

int check( int flag, char a[10])//isme galti hai
{
    if( a[0]==a[1]==a[2]=='X' ||
        a[3]==a[4]==a[5]=='X' ||
        a[6]==a[7]==a[8]=='X' ||
        a[0]==a[3]==a[6]=='X' ||
        a[1]==a[4]==a[7]=='X' ||
        a[2]==a[5]==a[8]=='X' ||
        a[0]==a[4]==a[8]=='X' ||
        a[2]==a[4]==a[6]=='X' )

    {
        flag= 1;
    }

    else 

    {
        if( a[0]==a[1]==a[2]=='0' ||
            a[3]==a[4]==a[5]=='0' ||
                a[6]==a[7]==a[8]=='0' ||
                a[0]==a[3]==a[6]=='0' ||
                a[1]==a[4]==a[7]=='0' ||
                a[2]==a[5]==a[8]=='0' ||
                a[0]==a[4]==a[8]=='0' ||
                a[2]==a[4]==a[6]=='0' )

        {
            flag= 2;
        }
    }
}
```

After returning the value of flag as pointed out, its still not working.

```
   #include<stdio.h>
int P1(int, char []), P2(int, char []), check( int, char []);
int main()
{
    char a[10]= "---------" ;
    int flag= 3, p, q;
    while( flag== 3)
    {   
        P1( p, a);  
        flag= check( flag, a); 
        if( flag== 1)
        {   printf("P1 WINS");}
        else
        {
            P2( q, a);
            flag= check( flag, a);
            if( flag== 2)
            {printf("P2 WINS");}
        }
    }
return 0;}

int P1(int p, char a[10])
{
    printf("P1: Which position?\n");
    scanf("%d", &p);
    a[p-1]= 'X';
    printf("%c %c %c\n%c %c %c\n%c %c %c\n", a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4], a[5], a[6], a[7], a[8]);return 0;
}

int P2(int q, char a[10])
{   
    printf("P2: Which position?\n");
    scanf("%d", &q);
    a[q-1]= '0';
    printf("%c %c %c\n%c %c %c\n%c %c %c\n", a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4], a[5], a[6], a[7], a[8]);return 0;
}

int check( int flag, char a[10])//isme galti hai
{   
    if( a[0]==a[1]==a[2]=='X' ||
        a[3]==a[4]==a[5]=='X' ||
        a[6]==a[7]==a[8]=='X' ||
        a[0]==a[3]==a[6]=='X' ||
        a[1]==a[4]==a[7]=='X' ||
        a[2]==a[5]==a[8]=='X' ||
        a[0]==a[4]==a[8]=='X' ||
        a[2]==a[4]==a[6]=='X' )

    {
        flag= 1;
    }

    else 

    {
        if( a[0]==a[1]==a[2]=='0' ||
            a[3]==a[4]==a[5]=='0' ||
                a[6]==a[7]==a[8]=='0' ||
                a[0]==a[3]==a[6]=='0' ||
                a[1]==a[4]==a[7]=='0' ||
                a[2]==a[5]==a[8]=='0' ||
                a[0]==a[4]==a[8]=='0' ||
                a[2]==a[4]==a[6]=='0' )

        {
            flag= 2;
        }
    }
    return flag;
}
```

If have tried replacing the characters with numbers and instead of 0 and X used 8 and 9 but that didn't execute correctly.

Comment: Please state what the question is exactly. Saying that there is a problem with the check function is not a question. Also please add what you did so far to try to fix the function.

Comment: This is possibly a homework question

Comment: You want to trace the code using a debugger to learn what is really going on.

Comment: I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

The conditional statements in your check function had some issues, also. Sorry about that. I made some corrections to your code and tested it, works ok.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int P1(int, char []), P2(int, char []), check( int, char []);
int main()
{
    char a[10]= "---------" ;
    int flag= 3, p, q;
    while( flag== 3)
    {   
        P1( p, a);  
        flag= check( flag, a); 
        if( flag== 1)
        {   printf("P1 WINS");}
        else
        {
            P2( q, a);
            flag= check( flag, a);
            if( flag== 2)
            {printf("P2 WINS");}
        }
    }
return 0;}

int P1(int p, char a[10])
{
    printf("P1: Which position?\n");
    scanf("%d", &p);
    a[p-1]= 'X';
    printf("%c %c %c\n%c %c %c\n%c %c %c\n", a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4], a[5], a[6], a[7], a[8]);return 0;
}

int P2(int q, char a[10])
{   
    printf("P2: Which position?\n");
    scanf("%d", &q);
    a[q-1]= '0';
    printf("%c %c %c\n%c %c %c\n%c %c %c\n", a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4], a[5], a[6], a[7], a[8]);return 0;
}

int check( int flag, char a[10])//isme galti hai
{   
    if( 
    (a[0]== 'X' && a[1]== 'X' && a[2]=='X') ||
    (a[3]== 'X' && a[4]== 'X' && a[5]=='X') ||
    (a[6]== 'X' && a[7]== 'X' && a[8]=='X') ||
    (a[0]== 'X' && a[3]== 'X' && a[6]=='X') ||
    (a[1]== 'X' && a[4]== 'X' && a[7]=='X') ||
    (a[2]== 'X' && a[5]== 'X' && a[8]=='X') ||
    (a[0]== 'X' && a[4]== 'X' && a[8]=='X') ||
    (a[2]== 'X' && a[4]== 'X' && a[6]=='X'))
    {
        flag= 1;
    }

    else 

    {
        if( 
    (a[0]== '0' && a[1]== '0' && a[2]=='0') ||
    (a[3]== '0' && a[4]== '0' && a[5]=='0') ||
    (a[6]== '0' && a[7]== '0' && a[8]=='0') ||
    (a[0]== '0' && a[3]== '0' && a[6]=='0') ||
    (a[1]== '0' && a[4]== '0' && a[7]=='0') ||
    (a[2]== '0' && a[5]== '0' && a[8]=='0') ||
    (a[0]== '0' && a[4]== '0' && a[8]=='0') ||
    (a[2]== '0' && a[4]== '0' && a[6]=='0'))

        {
            flag= 2;
        }
    }
    return flag;
}
```

ETA: look at this code, before you try and compile and run it, what do you expect the outcome to be?

```
int main(void)
{
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;

    if (a == b == 0)
        fprintf(stdout, "Both are zero.\n");
    else
        fprintf(stdout, "both are not zero.\n");

    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Think of it like this - the condition is evaluated to either true (1) or false (0)...do it backwards in your head:

```
if (a == b == 0)
```

Now, if we assign both a and b with values of 0:

```
int a = 0, b = 0;
```

The condition will be evaluated thus:

```
b == 0
```

first, the b == 0 part, which is true, we know b == 0 because we assigned it with that value...byut now what is the expression after that first condition is resolved?

```
if (a == 1)
```

Because b == 0 evaluates are true (1), you see?

You can do assignments in this fashion:

```
int a = b = 0;
```

but not conditional expressions because of how they're resolved.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I edited the code and returned the flag. The new code is in my question along with the original one.

Comment: Cool - did it fix the problem?

Comment: No. It executes the same way.

Comment: Works ok now, hope this helps - shouldn't be too tough for you to figure out what's happening with the changes I made.

Comment: Yes it works! But what was wrong with the earlier way to write the condition?

Comment: Well, you can't use conditional operators in that way in c. Too much to go into here in a simple comment - let me amend my answer.

Comment: No problem at all, always glad to be of help. Enjoy your coding,